# Can I overload pure virtual method in the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

In the example below I have a abstract class with pure virtual method (aka FUN1) and a normal method (aka FUN2).

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
        virtual void fun(int i) = 0; // FUN1
        void fun() { this->fun(123); } // FUN2
};

class B : public A
{
public:
        virtual void fun(int i) { std::cerr << i << std::endl; }
};

int main(int,char**)
{
        B b;
        b.fun();
}
```

Why can't I call FUN2 on derived class? g++ gives an error:

> main.cpp:19:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::fun()’

---

EDIT: note that [Overload of pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827632/overload-of-pure-virtual-function) question is different. I don't want to override methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overload of pure virtual function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827632/overload-of-pure-virtual-function)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how derived class member lookup works: in the expression `b.fun()`, `fun` is first looked up in the scope of `class B`, and the lookup finds `B::fun(int)`. So it stops and never finds `A::fun()`.

Relevant section of the standard is 10.2 [class.member.lookup]/4:

> If `C` contains a declaration of the name `f`, the declaration set contains every declaration of `f` declared in
>   `C` that satisfies the requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs. (...) If the resulting declaration set is not empty, the subobject set contains `C` itself, and calculation is complete.

To make the base class function directly accessible you can use a `using` declaration in the derived class, i.e. `using A::fun;`.

For methods that are implemented in the base class an alternative is sometimes to qualify to call, i.e. `b.A::fun()`.

Answer (score 7):

Try to add `using A::fun;` statement in B class :

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void fun(int i) = 0; // FUN1
    void fun() { this->fun(123); } // FUN2
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::fun;
    virtual void fun(int i) { std::cerr << i << std::endl; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    B b;
    b.fun();
    b.fun(5);
}
```

Comment: but why do I need it?

Comment: @user2449761 Since `fun()` isn't declared `virtual`, it has to be introduced explicitly in derived classes.

Comment: Note that `virtual` is a red herring here. Defining some function `foo` in B hides the functions `foo` from the base class unless you explicitly import them.