# Why GCC/Clang don't resolve an overriden method with the same name?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Suppose I have the struct `A` and I want to overload `virtual int f()` in the derived class `B`. Here's the full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual int f() = 0;
    int f(int i) { return i + f(); }
};

struct B : A
{
    int f() override { return 10; }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << B().f(3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile GCC says:

```
derived.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
derived.cpp:17:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::f(int)’
derived.cpp:17:25: note: candidate is:
derived.cpp:11:9: note: virtual int B::f()
derived.cpp:11:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Clang cannot process the code, too.

But if I try to rename all the `int f()` functions to `int g()` everything works fine. What's the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: Add `using A ::f;` in B, it will work. f in B is masking the one with 1 argument

Comment: [There's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29595219/10769689) the full answer